# How to create a custom dialog with embedded WebBrowser control for web authentication in installer using WiX

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm looking for a way to embed the webbrowser control to installer to perform web based authentication.
Is there any way to implement it?
Implementing simple dialog with webcontrol will be a good starting point for me.

Answer (score 1):

WIX is limited to the functionality MSI can contain. And Web Browser control isn't the one that supported.

As for workarounds:

- you can create separate Windows application with any control you want and launch it with Custom Action from WIX installer. It won't look and feel like WIX custom dialog, but the task will be done.
- create custom dialog with username-password and custom action that creates HTTP request with provided credentials to validate credentials. It won't display the site of course, but the authentication task can be still done this way.
- if you are using WIX 3.6, you can simply create a bootstrapper with WPF dialog. Again WPF allows you to do anything you need with WebBrowser control. That dialog will be shown before the installer runs actually, but you can pass arguments to the main MSI, like in silent mode. Without WIX 3.6 you also can do the same, but with a bit more work actually.